# ReferenceError: encrypt is not defined

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I think it should work

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const mongooseEncrytion = require("mongoose-encryption") ;

const secret ="Thisisourlittlesecret.";
userSchema.plugin(encrypt, { secret: secret ,encryptedFields: ['password'] });
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess, you have a typo here.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose"); 
const mongooseEncrytion = require("mongoose-encryption") ;

const secret ="Thisisourlittlesecret."; 

// replace encrypt with mongooseEncrytion
userSchema.plugin(mongooseEncrytion, { secret: secret ,encryptedFields: ['password'] });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change "encrypt" to "mongooseEncrytion" in this line:

```
userSchema.plugin(mongooseEncrytion, { secret: secret ,encryptedFields: ['password'] });
```

You have to use the same name which you have defined to require it.